# Changing datetime format android

Tags: android, datetime, simpledateformat

I have a string in this format "20140210084957" I want to convert it to local format. Am almost there except month is not correct, instead of FEB below code is giving JAN, how to fix this.

```
 String dt = valuelist[time];
    SimpleDateFormat datetime1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
    Date formatted = null;
    try {
        formatted =datetime1.parse(dt);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dt=formatted.toLocaleString();
        //dt = formatted.toString();
        Log.d("DT Formatted", ""+dt);
        valuelist[time] =dt;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use capital M for month i.e

```
 SimpleDateFormat datetime1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss")
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the line `SimpleDateFormat datetime1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");` with  this line : `SimpleDateFormat datetime1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");`

Answer (score 1):

Problem into month format. That should be `MM` instead of `mm`.

Change it to `MM`

Like

```
SimpleDateFormat datetime1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss"); // result for month is 01 or 02 or 03
```

And for Jan/ Feb/ Mar like output

yo should use `MMM` for month.

```
SimpleDateFormat datetime1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMMddhhmmss"); // Result of month is Jan or Feb or Mar
```

---

Read more about [***Date and Time Patterns***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to note: If you have written every pattern symbol in small letters and you don't print or parse AM/PM then the format symbol h is probably wrong since it indicates the 12-hour-clock which is worthless without AM/PM-marker. In this case you should also use big letter H instead, like M instead of m is right for months.